# I put an incorrect nationality on my Air Asia booking

Tags: air-travel, bookings, airasia

I accidentally forgot to change the Nationality on my Air Asia booking, so this in turn will be different to my passport nationality.
Does anyone know how I can fix it please? I'm really desperate as we fly out on Friday.

Answer (score 8):

AirAsia has a "Manage my booking" option on their website. I don't have an active booking with them so I can't tell if you can adjust this detail, but the website does say you can "update traveller details".

If that fails, you'll need to call their [call center](http://www.airasia.com/ot/en/contact-us/call-centre.page). Last time I had to do that, it took quite some time to get through so it is a good idea to call right as the call center opens for the day (I mean literally to the second, as they open) if you can manage it.

Comment: Note that AirAsia no longer has a call center. You can only chat with a bot and hope you reach some path that connects you to an agent.